# Django KeyError at forms.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, keyerror

I'm learning django and I'm playing around with forms and registering users.
When I submit the registration form with the username, email, password, and confirm password fields filled, I get an error that states:

`KeyError at director/register/ "confirm_password"`

However, when I look at the POST data in the error message I clearly see the data I'm trying to access.

[image: [see screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S19QH.png)]

`csrfmiddlewaretoken: blahblahblabh`

`username: dasdasd`

`email: dasd@dsada.com`

`password: test123!`

`confirm_password: test123!`

Below are the forms.py, portion of the views.py, register.html files.

forms.py

````
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, UserChangeForm

from .models import CustomUser

class CustomUserCreationForm(UserCreationForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email", "password")

class CustomUserChangeForm(UserChangeForm):

    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ("email", "password")

class RegisterUser(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=64, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=True)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=True)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return username
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email

    def clean_password(self):
        password = self.cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
        return password```
````

views.py (register_view)

```
def register_view (request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = RegisterUser(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = RegisterUser()
    return render(request, 'pokedex/register.html', {'form': form})
```

register.html

```
{% extends 'pokedex/layout.html' %}

{% block title %}Register{% endblock title %}


{% block body %}

<h1>Register</h1>

{% if form.errors %}
<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <ul>
        {% for error in form.errors.values %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{% url 'register' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>

{% endblock body %}
```

EDIT: Added Traceback

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/pokedex/register/

Django Version: 4.1.7
Python Version: 3.9.2
Installed Applications:
['pokedex',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Code\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 56, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Code\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Code\stepchallenge\pokedex\views.py", line 45, in register_view
    if form.is_valid():
  File "C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Code\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 205, in is_valid
    return self.is_bound and not self.errors
  File "C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Code\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 200, in errors
    self.full_clean()
  File "C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Code\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 437, in full_clean
    self._clean_fields()
  File "C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Code\env\lib\site-packages\django\forms\forms.py", line 452, in _clean_fields
    value = getattr(self, "clean_%s" % name)()
  File "C:\Users\Alice\Documents\Code\stepchallenge\pokedex\forms.py", line 38, in clean_password
    confirm_password = self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']

Exception Type: KeyError at /pokedex/register/
Exception Value: 'confirm_password'
```

Comment: What's the traceback? As text, please, rather than a screenshot.

Comment: @NickODell Updated with traceback

Comment: What is the Meta Class in RegisterUser looks like?

Comment: @NickODell I don't have a meta class set for the RegisterUserForm. That where i messed up isn't it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the [Django official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1) in the section [Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms) at [*Cleaning and validating fields that depend on each other*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/validation/#cleaning-and-validating-fields-that-depend-on-each-other), you cannot read `self.cleaned_data['confirm_password']` inside the function `clean_password`, as the field might not be populated yet.

I suggest you to do the validation overriding the `clean` function like this:

```py
class RegisterForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=64, required=True)
    email = forms.EmailField()
    password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=True)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(max_length=128, widget=forms.PasswordInput(), required=True)

    def clean_username(self):
        username = self.cleaned_data["username"]
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(username=username).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return username
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        if CustomUser.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
            raise forms.ValidationError("Email already exists")
        return email
    
    # Removed clean_password function to use the default validation
    
    # Moved password check after all field are cleaned
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        password = cleaned_data['password']
        confirm_password = cleaned_data['confirm_password']
        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Passwords do not match")
```

I suggest also to take a look to [Django official documentation - Forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms) as it describes how to avoid most errors.

Comment: I went over cleaning and validating link. From what I understand, should i do the same with username and email? Wouldn't it be the case for the username and password too? I'm checking for the username inside the clean_username method.

Just trying to understand. Thank you for all the help.

Comment: @rolyjin There are different ways to do form validation within Django but I generally use this, `clean_<field_name>` for field-wise, `clean` for form-wise, and `validate` to override validatiors. If this answer did indeed fixed your problem consider upvoting or marking as accepted answer